# Expected waiting time to board the train

Tags: probability

You arrive at a metro station at time t = 0. Train A can come anytime between [0,3] and train B can come anytime between [0,5]. You will board the train that arrives first. What is the expected waiting time before you get into the train?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the waiting time.
$$P(T > t) = P(\text{neither train arrives before time $t$}) = \begin{cases} 1 & t < 0 \\\frac{3-t}{3} \cdot \frac{5-t}{5} & t \in [0, 3] \\ 0 & t > 3 \end{cases}$$
Then using the [tail sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case_2) formula for expectation
$$E[T] = \int_0^\infty P(T > t) \, dt
= \frac{1}{15} \int_0^3(3-t)(5-t) \, dt
= \frac{1}{15}(15 \cdot 3 - \frac{8}{2} 3^2 + \frac{1}{3} 3^3)
= \frac{6}{5}.$$

Comment: This is assuming that the trains' arrival times are uniformly distributed over $[0,3]$ and $[0,5]$, correct?